Does $\sup_{x \in L} |f'(x)|$ always exist if $f$ is differentiable? ("Introduction to Analysis I" by Mitsuo Sugiura.)
I am reading "Introduction to Analysis I" by Mitsuo Sugiura.

Theorem
Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a differentiable function on $U$. Suppose the line segment $L = \{ g(t) = a + t \cdot (b - a) : t \in [0, 1] \}$, with endpoints $a$ and $b$, is contained in $U$. Then, the following inequality holds:
$$
|f(b) - f(a)| \leq \sqrt{m} \cdot \sup_{x \in L} |f'(x)| \cdot |b - a|.
$$

$|f'(x)|$ is the Frobenius norm of the matrix $f'(x)$.
If $f$ is a $C^1$ function, then $|f'|$ is a continuous function on $L$. So, $\sup_{x \in L} |f'(x)|=\max_{x \in L} |f'(x)|$ exists.
But the author didn't assume that $f$ is $C^1$.
Instead, the author assumed that $f$ is differentiable.
Does $\sup_{x \in L} |f'(x)|$ always exist if $f$ is differentiable?

$\sup$ always exists, it just might be $+\infty.$ Are you asking if $\sup$ is finite?

Yes. I asked if $\sup$ is finite. The author defines $\sup$ only for a set which has an upper bound in this book and doesn't define $\infty\cdot a$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

@ThomasAndrews thank you very much for your comment.

$U$ is defined as an open set. Look at $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$. How does it derivative behave? Does the derivative have a finite supremum?
In fact, suppose that the statement were different and that $U$ were defined as a bounded closed set. In this other case, look at $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that  $f(0)=0$ and also $f(x)=x^2 \sin\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ whenever $x\neq0$. By computing separately for $x=0$ and $x\neq0$, you can check that $f$ is differentiable but the derivative does not have a finite supremum.

Chris Sanders, thank you very much for your answer.

Note that the supremum in the question is taken over $L$ (line segment, closed), not $U$ (open). So the first part of the answer is not relevant, but the second part is (when substituting $L$ for $U$).

@Ingix thank you very much for your comment.
